# Execute two sql commands related in VB.NET

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to execute two related sql commands in a single function top update my column xamlfile by a new xamlfile --> u

Here's my code

```
Public Shared Function updatetest()

    Dim c As SqlConnection = openConnection("Data Source=GENIOP40;Initial Catalog=TF5100_new;Integrated Security=true")
    Dim c2 As SqlConnection = openConnection("Data Source=GENIOP40;Initial Catalog=TF5100_new;Integrated Security=true")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT xamlfile, id_wkfw_task from WKFW_Tasks Where xamlfile like '%ExecuteTask%' order by name", c)
    Dim rd As SqlDataReader = executereader(cmd)
    Dim listxaml As New List(Of String)
    While rd.Read
        Dim u As String = GetString(rd, "xamlfile")
        Dim Id As Guid = GetGuid(rd, "id_wkfw_task")

        u = Regex.Replace(u, "(?<=<t[1-2]|:ExecuteTask[^><]+)\bTache", "TaskID")

        u = u.Replace("'", "''")

        Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("UPDATE WKFW_Tasks set xamlfile=@xmlfile where id_wkfw_task=@id_t", c2)
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("xmlfile", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = u
        cmd2.Parameters.Add("id_t", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = Id
        cmd2.CommandTimeout = 0
        executeNonQuery(cmd2)
        c2.Close()

    End While
    rd.Close()
    c.Close()


End Function
```

My problem is : when I close the reader after the loop, my first command is no more executed, and I need it to be executed so my second command can work, and if I don't close my reader I have an error, any suggestions please ?

Comment: For example, you can solve it this way: load your resultset into a DataTable and then loop through the DataTable. Your SqlCommand is free for commands now.

Comment: How should I do it .. ?

Comment: You don't need two connections. Just add MultipleActiveResultSets=true; to your connectionstring

Comment: `Dim dt As New DataTable : dt.Load(rd)` and then `For Each dr as DataRow In dt.Rows : Next`

Answer (score 0):

Change your initial connectionstring to

```
Dim c As SqlConnection = openConnection("Data Source=GENIOP40;
         Initial Catalog=TF5100_new;Integrated Security=true;
         MultipleActiveResultSets=true")
```

[See MSDN on MultipleActiveResultSets](https://www.bing.com/search?q=MultipleActiveResultSets&qs=n&sk=&form=BDKTKB&pc=BDT5&shash=&BDParam=0000&mkt=en-US)
Now you don't need anymore to have the DataReader closed between the calls and you can execute the command using the only one connection. However I recommend to move the creation of the update command and its parameters outside the loop.
Inside the loop just update the parameter values and execute

```
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("UPDATE WKFW_Tasks set xamlfile=@xmlfile where id_wkfw_task=@id_t", c)
cmd2.Parameters.Add("xmlfile", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
cmd2.Parameters.Add("id_t", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)
While rd.Read
    ....

    cmd2.Parameters("xmlfile")..Value = u
    cmd2.Parameters("id_t").Value = Id
    executenonquery(cmd2)
 End While
```

Comment: Same problem.. It seems to take an eternity to execute but don't, but when I execute only the specific command with specific data in sql server it works perfectly..

Comment: Did you get any kind of error message? If yes, please report it

Comment: when I execute the cmd2 after the End While it works but only for the last data that the first command get, when the query is executed inside the while it doesn't work and it seems to take forever